# How to enable Huawei share in Mac Catalina?

Tags: mac, catalina, smb

I recently updated my mac to Catalina, and I share a lot of files using Huawei Share, but since the update I can't log in my phone.

I've read that I have to enable NetBIOS on using terminal:

```
echo "[default]" | sudo tee -a /etc/nsmb.conf
echo "port445=both" | sudo tee -a /etc/nsmb.conf
```

When i did that, did nothing!

Comment: WHere is the note that said you have to enable netbios - presumably it said more than that

Comment: Is Huawei Share 32 or 64bit?  If not 64bit, it's not going to work on Catalina.